# jQuery plugin mutliple times on the same website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I do have some basic knowledge about jQuery and I'm trying to create a plugin.
In this particular case, it's a dropdown element which is being rendered.

Now, everything is working when there's only one dropdown on the website, but when I do have multiple dropdown elements, than it's not working anymore.

This is the code on how I activate the plugin:

```
$('#OfficeUI .dropdown').each(function(index, item) {
    $(item).OfficeUIDropdown();
});
```

And here's the full source code of my plugin:

```
$.fn.OfficeUIDropdown = function() {
    var dropdownElement = $(this); 
    $.fn.selectedItem = ''; 


    $(dropdownElement).addClass('no-select'); // Adds a class that ensure that text-selection for this element is disabled.
    $(dropdownElement).append('<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>'); 
    $.fn.hasFocus = function() { return dropdownElement.hasClass('focus'); };

    $.fn.isActive = function() { return dropdownElement.hasClass('active'); };

    $.fn.isMenuOpened = function() { return dropdownElement.hasClass('opened'); };

    $.fn.ToggleOpen = function() {
        // Check if the menu is opened or closed, based on that, hide or show the menu.
        if (dropdownElement.isMenuOpened()) {
            $('.elements', dropdownElement).hide();
            dropdownElement.removeClass('opened');
        } else {
            $('.elements', dropdownElement).show('slide', { direction: 'up' }, 100);
            dropdownElement.addClass('opened');
        }
    }

    dropdownElement.hover(function() {
        dropdownElement.addClass('focus');
    }, function() {
        if (!$(dropdownElement).is(':focus') && !dropdownElement.isMenuOpened()) {
            $(dropdownElement).removeClass('focus');
        }
    });

    dropdownElement.focusout(function() {
        dropdownElement.removeClass('active');
    });

    $('i', dropdownElement).click(function() {
        dropdownElement.ToggleOpen(dropdownElement);
    })

    $('.elements li', dropdownElement).click(function() {
        var selectedLiText = $(this).html();
        $('.legend', dropdownElement).html(selectedLiText);

        $.fn.selectedItem = selectedLiText; // Set a property to we know the item which has been selected.

        var attribute = dropdownElement.attr('data-on-change');
        if (typeof attribute !== 'undefined' && attribute != '') { eval(attribute); }

        dropdownElement.ToggleOpen();

        dropdownElement.removeClass('focus');
    });

    return this;
}
```

I know it's quite a it of code but I really do hope that someone can help me out on this. Any ideas on how this plugin can be improved are welcome.

Here's a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24aq3ffn/) to demonstrate the problem.

Try to click on the A of the first dropdown and the second dropdown goes open.
I really don't understand it.

Comment: Why are you binding all of those functions and variables into public jQuery functions?

Comment: Well, as told, I do have a basic knowledge about jQuery so it isn't perfect. I know. Any advice on how to do it correct is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of how dropdownElement gets defined within the plugin, when you call other functions, the definition of dropdownElement has changed. You can remedy this by binding your function declarations to a specific scope, **this**.

```
$.fn.hasFocus = function() { return this.hasClass('focus'); };
$.fn.isActive = function() { return this.hasClass('active'); };
$.fn.isMenuOpened = function() { return this.hasClass('opened'); };
$.fn.ToggleOpen = function() {
    // Check if the menu is opened or closed, based on that, hide or show the menu.
    if (this.isMenuOpened()) {
        $('.elements', this).hide();
        this.removeClass('opened');
    } else {
        $('.elements', this).show();
        this.addClass('opened');
    }
}
```

See it in action **[on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24aq3ffn/1/)**.

Comment: Also, your show function was throwing an error in the console. I didn't look into that one very much, just removed the specifics of it.

Comment: That's not a problem. It's working fine, but in your first comment you told me that I'm creating public jQuery functions. How should I avoid that one?

Comment: You could bind them as private functions and just pass in your element as a parameter. That's a little more enclosed: https://jsfiddle.net/24aq3ffn/2/